# node.js promise not working properly for map within map syntax

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, aws-s3-client

I am trying to run the code below and for some strange reason in the debugger it gets to the send call and just jumps out to the calling function without ever continuing to the return line.  I am not sure what could be going on here.  If I take the code out of the maps and run for a single case it seems to work.  Of course, I need the loops so that is not possible.  What could I be doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

calling function code:

```
templates.map(async (template) => {
    await Promise.all(userJobs.map(async (job) => {
        **if (job.emailAddress && job.emailAddress.length > 0) {**

            if (job?.optedIn === null || job?.optedIn === undefined ||
                job?.optedIn === 1 || job?.optedIn === true) {
                if (job.templateAttributes && Object.keys(job.templateAttributes).length > 0) {
                    if (job.path) {
                        await setupTemplate({
                            firstName: job.firstName,
                            emailAddress: job.emailAddress,
                            templateAttributes: job.templateAttributes,
                            path: job.path
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }));
});
```

setupTemplate function code:

```
try {
    if (path) {
        const htmlString = await convertObjectToString({
            key: path,
            bucket: process.env.AWS_TEMPLATES
        });

        return htmlString
    }
} catch (e) {
    throw e;
}
```

convertObjectToString function code:

```
try {
    const client = new S3Client({
        region:'us-west-1',
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        }
    });
    const command = new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key
    });

**const response = await client.send(command);**
    return await response.Body.transformToString();
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
} finally {
    console.log('Made it to the end');
}
```

Comment: Ideally your userJobs map would actually be a filter, to remove the undesirable jobs per your series of if statements, and only then a map that returns the result of calling setupTemplate.

Comment: Please provide code that is runnable, including the function headers, driver code, mock API if necessary... Remove what is irrelevant to the problem (like all those nested `if` conditions, ...)